# Crash when create multiple cell object using MKSlidingTableViewCell for cell animation in iOS 11.4

Tags: swift, ios11

I am using MKSlidingTableViewCell for cell animation. But App goes to crash when try create multiple cell object in iOS 11.4 but its runing well in iOS 10 . Crash message like Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path). Cell identifier: AllItemsCell, index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

Below is my code. Please help.

```
        let cell : MKSlidingTableViewCell? = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "container", for: indexPath) as? MKSlidingTableViewCell)

        let cellForeground : AllItemsCell? = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AllItemsCell", for: indexPath) as? AllItemsCell)

        let cellBack : AllItemsCell? = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "backgroundcell", for: indexPath) as? AllItemsCell)

        cell?.foregroundView = cellForeground
        cell?.drawerView = cellBack
        cell?.drawerRevealAmount = 555
```

Comment: Crash reason  as well as fix is given in crash message itself

Answer (score 3):

According to the crash you want to change this

```
let cell : MKSlidingTableViewCell? = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "container", for: indexPath) as? MKSlidingTableViewCell)
```

to

```
let cell : MKSlidingTableViewCell? = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"container") as? MKSlidingTableViewCell)
```

//

Do same for remaining 2